# Local development server for AppEngine Standard and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How is one meant to develop against a local Cloud Datastore instance using NodeJS with Appengine Standard?

Comparatively - the Go development environment ships with a local Datastore server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what I know, there's no bundled local Cloud Datastore server for NodeJS but you can use the [Cloud Datastore emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator):

> The Google Cloud Datastore emulator provides local emulation of the production Cloud Datastore environment. You can use the emulator to develop and test your application locally.

Also, I've found a [npm package that supports the Cloud Datastore emulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-datastore-emulator). It seems a little bit outdated but has some information about how to connect to it with NodeJS and such that could be useful.