# NodeJS Local Datastore GAE Whit UI

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I use GAE with java in dev mode, I have a server with access to the local database (and its user interface).

Now I want to have the same thing with the NodeJs server.
How can I have a local data store with the user interface?

Comment: Please elaborate on what you would like to achieve. By 'Datastore', do you mean the GCP product '[Firestore in Datastore mode](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-datastore)'?

Comment: Yes I’m talking about GCP but my goal is just to accès  to a local google BDD in dev mod with its UI.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local development server for AppEngine Standard and NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51667246/local-development-server-for-appengine-standard-and-nodejs)